# Violin plot of a list of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, violin-plot

I have some data in the format:

```
[array([[0, 1, 2]], dtype=int64), array([[1, 2, 3]], dtype=int64)]
```

My data can be generated using:

```
di_DFs = {}
groups = [1,2]
for grp in groups:
    di_DFs[grp] = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [grp-1],
                                'B' : [grp],
                                'C' : [grp+1]})
data = []
for k in di_DFs:
    data.append(di_DFs[k].iloc[[0]].values)
```

I can plot it:

```
for v in data:
    plt.scatter(range(len(v[0])),v[0])
```

[image]

I would like to get a violin plot with 3 vertical violins where my pairs of points are in the scatter plot please, to compare the distributions within my arrays. I tried:

```
for v in data:
    plt.violinplot(v)
```

But I got:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to re-format my data:

```
df_Vi = pd.DataFrame({'Z' : data[0][0],
                      'Y' : data[1][0]}, index=range(len(data[0][0])))
    
plt.violinplot(df_Vi)
```

[image]

Or, a version that works with more data:

```
di_DFs = {}
groups = [1,2,0,7]
for grp in groups:
    di_DFs[grp] = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [grp-1],
                                'B' : [grp],
                                'C' : [grp+1]})
data = []
for k in di_DFs:
    data.append(di_DFs[k].iloc[[0]].values)

Indexes = range(len(groups))
    
df_Vi = pd.DataFrame()
    
for inD in Indexes:
    df_Po = pd.DataFrame({inD : data[inD][0]},
                          index=range(len(data[0][0])))
    
    df_Vi = pd.concat([df_Vi, df_Po], axis=1)

plt.violinplot(df_Vi)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like this:

```
for v in data:
    plt.violinplot(v)
```

Plots this:

[image]

Since the example dataset has only a few points, you will not see much of distribution but more like flat dashes/points. But try with more data points and it will do the needed.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried that, both with the data in the example and with more data points. Your figure shows what I want but your code doesn't give that with my data. I'll edit the question to show what it gives. I think I need to re-format my data some how.